# Adding related list item to layout on install

Tags: sobject, page-layout, related-list

I have an application that has a custom related list. At the moment, the related list needs to be added manually after the app has been installed through the page layout.

Is it possible to add this automatically on the install?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

You can include a page layout in your package and that can include a related list, but to add the related list to an existing page layout I don't believe is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If this isn't possible, is it somehow possible to have default fields within a related list so that the user doesn't have to add those themselves too?